# Multithreading in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

Please help me to make my script multithreaded. I have read the documentation for the [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads%3a%3ashared) module but it didn't help to understand how to do it

```
    use threads;
use threads::shared;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $NUM_WORKERS = 2;

sub worker {
   my ($i) = @_;
   my ($web, $ck) = browser();
    ($username, $password) = split ':', $acc;
    my $url = 'http://www.site.ru/?tkn'. int(rand(10000));
    my $response = $web->post($url, Content =>
                    [//////]);
    while(1)
    {
        my $url = 'http://www.site.ru/dk?st.page='.$i.'&st.name=%D0%B0';
        my $response  = $web->get($url);
        @list = ($response->content =~ /card_wrp"><div class="photoWrapper"><div><a href="\/(.*?)\?/g);
        @popl = ($response->content =~/<\/div><div class="info">(.*?)<\/div>/g);

        for ($j = 0; $j <= scalar @list - 1; $j++)
        {
            $popl[$j] =~ s/&nbsp;//g;
            open F, ">>gr.txt";
            print F $list[$j].':'.$popl[$j]. "\n";
            close F;
        }
        print "[+] Page $i \n";

    }
}

my $i :shared = 1;
my $last = 79265;
my @workers;
for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (1) {
         my $i;
         {
            lock $I;
            return if $i == $last;
            $i = ++$I;
         }
         worker($i);
      }
   };
}

$_->join() for @workers;
sub browser 
{
 my $web = new LWP::UserAgent;
 my $ck = new HTTP::Cookies;
    $web->cookie_jar($ck);
    $web->agent('Opera/9.80 (Windows 7; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50');
    $web->requests_redirectable(0); 

    $web->timeout(5);
 return $web, $ck;
}
sub loadf {
    open (F, "<".$_[0]) or erroropen($_[0]); 
    chomp(my @data = <F>);
    close F;
    return @data;
}
```

I can't understand what variable I need to share. Thanks a lot to all members who will help me

Comment: The solution I gave to your [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168495/thread-shared-perl) applies here too.

Answer (score 8):

If you didn't have threads, the work loop would look like something like

```
for my $i (1..79265) {
   worker($i);
}
```

The problem is that the variable isn't shareable and  `for` maintains an internal state that can't be shared, so we need to rewrite it into something without those issues.

Option 1:

```
my @a = 1..79265;
while (@a) {
   worker(shift(@a));
}
```

Option 2:

```
my $i = 0;
while (++$i <= 79265) {
   worker($i);
}
```

All that's needed to parallelize either version is to make sure `@a`/`$i` doesn't change between the time you check it and the time you use it. This is done by adding a lock.

Option 1:

```
my @a :shared = 1..79265;
while (1) {
   my $i;
   { lock @a; return if !@a; $i = shift(@a); }
   worker($i);
}
```

Option 2:

```
my $I :shared = 1;
while (1) {
   my $i;
   { lock $I; $i = $I; return if ++$I > 79265; }
   worker($i);
}
```

Option 1 is the basis of the Thread::Queue solution that follows (although it could be used as-is). Option 2 is used as-is down below.

---

I usually use [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue) or [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue::Any):

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw( );

my $NUM_WORKERS = 5;

sub worker {
   my ($i) = @_;
   ... put your download code here ...
}

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
my @workers;
for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (defined(my $i = $q->dequeue())) {
         worker($i);
      }
   };
}

$q->enqueue($_) for 1..79265;
$q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;
$_->join() for @workers;
```

But we can easily do without here:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $NUM_WORKERS = 5;

sub worker {
   my ($i) = @_;
   ... put your download code here ...
}

my $I :shared = 1;
my $last = 79265;
my @workers;
for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (1) {
         my $i;
         {
            lock $I;
            $i = $I;
            return if ++$I > $last;
         }
         worker($i);
      }
   };
}

$_->join() for @workers;
```

Comment: @user1614240, Added explanation.

Comment: Thanks I re-write m code but it doesn't work, see it in the topic

Comment: @user1614240, How does it not work? Tested my code. Fixed a bug with 1 being skipped. I doubt this new problem of yours has anything to do with your original question. Please post a new question with **minimal**, **runnable** demonstration of the problem.