# Trying to process 100 URL requests. Should I use perl CPAN HTTP::Async? Mojo?

Tags: multithreading, perl, asynchronous, mojolicious, mojo

I'm trying to create a program that can connect to 100 URLs at a time, and depending on the output of each connection (ie, success on an HTTP connect) then the perl script would go to function x, or what not. The best I could come up with, is this script. But I'd like it to connect to 100 URLs simultaneously, or in parallel, each returning a response (so I should get 100 or so at the end of the LWP timeout) to figure out what I want to do next. However, most examples I've seen, tend to do one URL at time. It may run through 20-30 real fast, but if one is down, that is where the slowdown really begins.

```
use Mojo::Client;
use Mojo::Transaction;

my $client = Mojo::Client->new;

my $tx  = Mojo::Transaction->new_get('http://labs.kraih.com');
my $tx2 = Mojo::Transaction->new_get('http://mojolicious.org');
$tx2->req->headers->expect('100-continue');
$tx2->req->body('foo bar baz');

$client->process_all($tx, $tx2);

print $tx->res->code;
print $tx2->res->code;
print $tx2->res->content->file->slurp;
```

However, it creates variables for each transaction. If I'm going to do 100 sites, creating $tx1 - $tx 100 would be painful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's [easy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12168814/589924) using threads, but I would use [Net::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Curl::Multi) again. Very capable, and very low overhead.

Comment: You might fork the process before checking the URL as many times as your URL. That way, each new process would handle its request and if a process is stalled, you don't care because the other would process normally. Your process would have a state variable (main or fork). It it's a main, it only forks, setting an variable containing an URL. It it's a fork, it queries the URL. Mmmm... It looks like threads eh?

Comment: [LWP::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel)? You don't need threads, just asynchronous IO.

Comment: Do you need to do anything after a request completes, based on how it went?  Write logs, run some follow-up processing, check status ...?  Or nothing at all?

Comment: zdim, yes! Only URLs that were successfully fetched would have some sort of follow-up processing. The ones that didn't connect or died out are left to die out happily in the program.

Comment: I had the same question and ended up using [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3A%3AHTTP). [Here's my script.](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/urlheadinfo)  It works well, but I still don't know about the merits and drawbacks of the various available libraries.

Comment: @LukasNelson  OK. Do successful requests need to pass any particular information back to parent/controller, or is it enough to know that they were successful?

Comment: zdim, Just knowing it was successful is perfect. No parent or controller, just a script to check many HTTP sites for to see if they are responding.

Comment: @LukasNelson I was going to then suggest (post) some basic fork-based code, whereby a SIGCHLD handler can record success/fail by exit codes. However, by your comment you did it with `P::FM`, which also allows you to (more easily) do it a bunch at a time.  I guess you found out how to pass data back from children to parent, as well (it's in the docs if you didn't).  So I guess all is well :)

Comment: @LukasNelson  Btw, when you post a message you need to say `@user` for the `user` to be notified. Sometimes it works without that, if there are only two users posting comments (I think) but in general it is needed. I didn't see your comment until now, when I came back to check up on the page.  Otherwise I would've been notified and had a chance to see it hours and hours ago. Just info :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my basic suggestion: create a process for each url and let the process handle it independently from the other.
Note that if you need to log, all processes could share a handle on a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;use warnings;

my @url = ('url1','url2','url3');

my $pid;
my $url_to_process;

foreach my $url (@url) {
    $pid = fork; #create new process.
    unless ($pid) {
        $url_to_process = $url;
        last;
    } #end loop if we are a child
}

unless ($pid) {
    print "$$: $url_to_process\n"; # or do anything you like with the url
}
```

Comment: Thanks, forking worked. I ended up using Parallel::ForkManager and followed the example, which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: [code]  use Parallel::ForkManager;

  my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);

  DATA_LOOP:
  foreach my $data (@all_data) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next DATA_LOOP;

    ... do some work with $data in the child process ...

    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
  }[/code]

Comment: Oh I see! It's the same thing but with advanced features such as a maximum number of children. Neat. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Each child process drops out of the loop and proceeds to execute all other code later in the program.  All children see their PID as 0, so all of them rush to where you imply the processing happens.  This happens very _very_ quickly and in general they don't hit the processing code in order in which they are created -- you have races going on. There is absolutely _no guarantee_ that all kids process all and different URL's.  A common way of doing it is to have processing code inside the loop and then `exit`.

Comment: Children also need to pass information back to the parent. In this problem fail/succeed is good enough, so that can be done via exit codes. However, the parent can't do a blocking wait since some children may well hang. Thus you can do a non-blocking `waitpid` in a SIGCHLD handler, where each child would write to a simple hash (say).  The parent can then sit in a loop after the `foreach` and poll that hash. This would also need some cut-out time, in case some processes are indeed hanging.

Comment: Also, you can't have kids write to the same file.  Those writes surely come out of order, and even if it's just a line per process the _lines_ themselves get cut by others.  Try, it's fun to see the mayhem that comes out :)  Of course, in some longer processing there is less of a chance for this to happen ... but it becomes a game of chance.

Comment: About the last point, it's not such a big deal: you can identify each line with a key - as each URL is a different process - and use grep to follow the processing of a given URL.